# Marklogic Attribute range Index scope

Tags: indexing, marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using the attribute "ID" in my search query. So I plan to create the attribute range index for attribute "ID" for the below sample XML.

```
 <head>
    <title>
    <note ID=20 >1</note>
      <to>Tove</to>
      <from>Jani</from>
      <heading>Reminder</heading>
      <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
      </title>
    </head>
```

My question is which tag `(<Head> or <Title> or <Note>)` I need to refer as "Parent Local Name" to have maximum effect.

Answer (score 0):

the `note` element, because the `ID` is an attribute within this element

Comment: Thanks, I will try this .

Answer (score 0):

The `<head>` or `<title>` tags do not contain any attribute, the attribute belongs to the `<note>` tag. 
Also, you can query this attribute range index through this

```
cts:search(//head,
    cts:element-attribute-value-query(
      xs:QName("note"),
      xs:QName("ID"),
      "20"))
```